# Why is this stored with ".xls" in the file name twice

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the following snippet save a file as .xls.xls

i.e. the xls appears twice? The sheetname has the ".xls" ending, but it is not something that I have specified...

Please note that Stack snippet does appear to allow window.open (is this a bug - am I missing a ref?), but if you copy to FireFox you will see the issue.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr>";
  var table = document.getElementById("tab2excel");

  var style;
  for (var j = 0; j < table.rows.length; j++) {
    style = table.rows[j].className.split(" ");
    if (style.length < 2)
      tab_text = tab_text + table.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
  }

  tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table2xl" id="tab2excel">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Bear</td>
        <td>23.8</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>Kite</td>
        <td>3.8</td>
        <td>77</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

) {
        var tab_text = "";
        var table = document.getElementById(tblId);

```
    var style;
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows.length; j++) {
        style = table.rows[j].className.split(" ");
        if (style.length < 2)
            tab_text = tab_text + table.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");


    return window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
```

}

Comment: Stack Snippets are sandboxed to prevent security issues (which can be had when using `window.open`. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337916/why-is-window-open-blocked if you're curious.

Comment: So, your HTML gets clobbered by your function there, since you're adding the ending `</tr>` on every row, but not the opening `<tr>` (which is not included in the `innerHTML`). I doubt that has anything to do with why you're getting the duplicate extensions, but thought it would be good to point out...

Comment: But I can do it in jsFiddle and Stackoverflow is pushing me to use snippets!

Comment: I don't think it's pushing you to use snippets, but the code should be available in the question itself, not *just* on jsfiddle.net.